# How to filter an array of objects by the sum of a value

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
if ( aTimesContacted > bTimesContacted ) {
                return 1
            }

            if ( bTimesContacted > aTimesContacted ) {
                return -1
            }

            return 0;
```

---

Here is an mock dataset of what I am working with:

```
mock = [
  {
    data: {
      person: {
        contact: {
          list: [
            {
               history: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
               type: {}
            }
            {
               history: [{...}],
               type: {}
            }
          ]
        },
        asdf: {...}
      },
      bleh: {...}
    },
    something: {...}
  },
  {...},
  {...}
]
```

I am trying to filter the mock data by the TOTAL length of history within each parent object.

This is what my function looks like right now:

```
function filterByContactAmount():void {
        let sorted = data.sort((a:any, b:any) => {
            let aTimesContacted:number = a.data.person.contact.list.reduce((acc:any, val:any) => acc + val.history.length, 0)
            let bTimesContacted:number = b.data.person.contact.list.reduce((acc:any, val:any) => acc + val.history.length, 0) 

            return ( aTimesContacted > bTimesContacted ) ? a - b : b - a
        })

        setData(sorted)
    }
```

I am correctly getting the amount of times contacted within the variables i set(`aTimesContacted` , `bTimesContacted`) but when I log the sorted array, nothing changed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your return is wrong `return ( a > b ) ? a - b : b - a` will always give a positive number (or zero), use `return a-b` or the reverse if you want a reversed sort `return b-a`

Comment: If I just do return a - b, how is it checking which has been contacted more...?

Comment: sort expects positive number, zero, or negative number as a return value so if `a=15` and `b=6` `a-b = 9` so `a` is sorted first, conversely if `b=15` and `a=6` it will be `-9` so `b` is sorted first. note by `a-b` i mean `aTimesContacted` and `bTimesContacted`

Comment: a and b are objects... They aren't numbers. If you actually read through the post, you can see that I first need to count up the amount of times each user has been counted. I store the amount into the variables: `aTimesContacted` and `bTimesContacted`. I need to compare those 2 values and sort the objects accordingly

Comment: Yea i shortened the names to `a` and `b` to save space in the comment, forgot to mention that. Actually in your code you are using them wrong as well (ie you are trying to do math on the objects instead of the times)

Comment: What do you mean I am trying to do math on the objects instead of the times?

Comment: you had in your code `? a - b : b - a`, so as you noted `a` and `b` are objects so this is trying to do math on your objects. It should be `aTimesContacted - bTimesContacted`

Comment: Ahhh I think I get it. Looked through sort docs